# Excel VBA: copy lots of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I´d like to copy all data from a Sheet to another sheet of another new Excel file. I have tried this:

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
wkb.SaveAs myNewFile
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate
Set Ticker = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Ticker.Copy
wkb.Worksheets(1).Activate
Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
wkb.Save
wkb.Close
```

The problem I´ve found is that it won´t work when there are a great amount of columns (for instance, from A to OV). Do you know other way to to this?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just copy the sheet?

Answer (score 4):

You could skip the clipboard altogether:

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
copyAddress$ = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address

With wkb
    .SaveAs myNewFile
    .Sheets(1).Range(copyAddress).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range(copyAddress).Value
    .Save
    .Close True '// Assuming you would want to save changes
End With
```

Or you could just copy the entire sheet:

```
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2").Copy Before:=wkb.Sheets(1)
```